# Determine if HTTP request to a service is within or outside of the kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a use-case where I need to use different headers for calls going outside the cluster. How to determine if the HTTP request is made to a service outside the kubernetes cluster ?

Comment: A HTTP request has nothing to do with Kubernetes. So, unless somebody is giving you extra information (through headers, request parameters, source IP etc.) you cannot know. And that's precisely how it should be, the internet is already a huge mess.

Comment: Most likely there will be some information in the headers, though. Depending on your ingress controller or load balancer.  X-Forwarded-For, Referrer and so on.

Comment: Thats said, if I understand your q, correctly, If you use an ingress controlller, only external requests will g though this controller typically. So you could add the headers there as you know services inside the cluster will be calling each other via core dns. Nginx for example has the add_header directive, to add headers to response.